# Drag and drop imagebuttons having issues with onDrag

Tags: java, android, drag-and-drop, imagebutton, applicationcontext

I am developing an android app where the user can purchase buildings that are imagebuttons that implement the drag and drop api. My issue is that when the user buys two buildings, say colonyHutOne and colonyHutTwo, there is an issue with the x and y coordinates being saved in the onDrag. In my onDrag I pass in which building number in the onDragListener so i know what building i am dealing with in the onDrag class. This way i can save the coordinates to the appropriate building. The problem is that no matter what building number i pass into the onDrag, the most recently created building is the one that takes the coordinates. In the onDrag, it receives building number two every time even when its the first building that is being dragged (which is building number one). I have no idea if this has something to do with context that is passed to the onDrag or if it is because the onDragListeners are declared before the drag is made so it just takes the last created imagebutton. I have no idea how to get past this issue. Please help.

Here is the code for setting the on Drag listener of both buildings:

```
findViewById(R.id.topHalf).setOnDragListener(new ColonyHutDrag(getApplicationContext(), 1));
findViewById(R.id.bottomHalf).setOnDragListener(new ColonyHutDrag(getApplicationContext(), 1));
FrameLayout.LayoutParams  param1 = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
newColonyHutFrame.addView(newColonyHutOne, param1);

findViewById(R.id.topHalf).setOnDragListener(new ColonyHutDrag(getApplicationContext(), 2));
findViewById(R.id.bottomHalf).setOnDragListener(new ColonyHutDrag(getApplicationContext(), 2));
FrameLayout.LayoutParams  param1 = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
newColonyHutFrame.addView(newColonyHutTwo, param1);
```

Here is the onDrag class:

```
public class ColonyHutDrag implements OnDragListener
{
    SharedPreferences prefs;
    Context passedContext;
    Database data;
    int buildingNum = 0;

    public ColonyHutDrag(Context applicationContext, int num) 
    {
        passedContext = applicationContext;
        buildingNum = num;
    }//end constructor

    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) 
    {
        float x = 0, y = 0;
        switch(event.getAction())
        {
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
            //drag has started
            break;

        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
            //being dragged
            break;

        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
            //stop drag
            break;

        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION:
            //find drag location
            break;

        case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
            if (v == v.findViewById(R.id.bottomHalf))
            {
                //find position where dropped
                x = event.getX();
                y = event.getY();

                //save the coordinates that the building was dropped at
                data = new Database(passedContext);
                data.open();
                if (buildingNum == 1)
                {
                    data.colonyHutOneXEntry(x);
                    data.colonyHutOneYEntry(y);
                    Toast.makeText(passedContext, "Going in1 -> x: " + x + " y: " + y, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }//end if
                else if (buildingNum == 2)
                {
                    data.colonyHutTwoXEntry(x);
                    data.colonyHutTwoYEntry(y);
                    Toast.makeText(passedContext, "Going in2 -> x: " + x + " y: " + y, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }//end else if

                data.close();

                //use this to fix building loadup glitch
                View view = (View) event.getLocalState();
                ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
                group.removeView(view);
                FrameLayout contain = (FrameLayout) v;
                contain.addView(view);
                view.setX(x - (view.getWidth()/2));
                view.setY(y - (view.getHeight()/2));
                view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }//end if
            else
            {
                View view = (View) event.getLocalState();
                view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }//end else
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }//end switch
        return true;
    }//end onDrag function
}//end ColonyHutOneDrag class
```

Here is the onTouchlistener for the drag and drop:

```
public class BuildingsClick implements OnTouchListener 
{   
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
    {
        ClipData.Item item = new ClipData.Item((CharSequence)v.getTag());

        String[] mimeTypes = { ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN }; 
        ClipData data = new ClipData(v.getTag().toString(), mimeTypes, item); 
        DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(v); 

        v.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, v, 0);
        v.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        return false;   
    }//end onTouch function

}//end BuildingsClick class
```

I really appreciate any help. I have no idea how to fix the problem. It is almost like since the second building is being dealt with, then the first one can no longer be referenced.
Thanks guys.

Edit:

Code in BuildingsClick class

```
//find which building is being dragged
if (v.getTag() == "NewColonyHutOne")
{
    ColonyHutDrag.setType(ColonyHutOneDrag.getType());
}//end if
else if (v.getTag() == "NewColonyHutTwo")
{
    ColonyHutDrag.setType(ColonyHutTwoDrag.getType());
}//end if
```

Code for ColonyHutOneDrag class:

```
public class ColonyHutOneDrag extends ColonyHut
{

    @Override
    public int getType() 
    {
        return 1;
    }//end getType

}//end ColonyHutOneDrag
```

The code for the ColonyHutTwoDrag class is the same as the first one but returns 2.

This is the getType in ColonyHutDrag:

```
public void setType(int type)
{
    buildingNum = type;
}//end setType
```

Comment: You cannot reference the class like that. You are calling a method on the `ColonyHutDrag` CLASS not an INSTANCE. You must call non static methods on an INSTANCE, you called it on a CLASS, and your IDE, not finding a static method of that name, suggested you make the non-static one of the same name static, to silence that error (and requiring your other methods be static). What you REALLY need to do is get an INSTANCE of `ColonyHutDrag`, like so: `ColonyHutDrag colonyHutListener = new ColonyHutDrag`. Store that, pass it to your view as a listener, then use `colonyHutListener.getType()`.

Comment: Also, a good java book (or online resources) may do you a whole lot of good, as this is simple stuff.

Comment: Crap I see a typo in my comment and it has been too long to edit. You want to instantiate like this: `ColonyHutDrag colonyHutListener = new ColonyHutDrag(getApplicationContext());` (I forgot the parentheses at the end!). Store ONE of these as a variable and pass it to EVERYTHING that needs `ColonyHutDrag` and you should be golden.

Comment: @MeetTitan So I create an instance of ColonyHutDrag but if I do it the way you said in your comment it won't work. getType is in the ColonyHutOneDrag class. It makes me think that you mean that I need to create an instance of the ColonyHutOneDrag class that way i can access the getType method in that class like so: ColonyHutDrag.setType(colonyHutOneListen.getType()); This requires it to be static as well. I am sorry if I am missing something that you are trying to say.

Comment: No I messed up my comment, but that is NOT what I meant. You need to be able to `colonyHutListener.setType(ColonyHutOne.getType());`. `getType()` can be static, because what that says is every instance of `ColonyHutOne` should return the same. That is ok because every instance should return the same type value. What we want though is for `setType()` not to be static, and to achieve that we must call `ColonyHutDrag colonyHutListener = new ColonyHutDrag(getApplicationContext());`, THEN WE SET TYPE LIKE SO: `colonyHutListener.setType(ColonyHutOne.getType());`. Sorry about my typo.

Comment: @MeetTitan Don't answer that. I realize what I was doing...makes me feel like a beginner...I had originally been using instances of the classes to access them but I was only using it on the ColonyHutOneDrag class...not the ColonyHutDrag class as well. Thank you for your help. I see my mistake here.

Comment: Too late :-P. Please be sure to accept and up-vote if you feel I've helped you (this was a multiple part question, glad it's over!). Good luck in your Java endeavors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are incorrectly as assigning the `OnDragListener`s again.

You can't

```
findViewById(R.id.topHalf).setOnDragListener(new ColonyHutDrag(getApplicationContext(), 1));
findViewById(R.id.bottomHalf).setOnDragListener(new ColonyHutDrag(getApplicationContext(), 1));
FrameLayout.LayoutParams  param1 = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

and then

```
findViewById(R.id.topHalf).setOnDragListener(new ColonyHutDrag(getApplicationContext(), 2));
findViewById(R.id.bottomHalf).setOnDragListener(new ColonyHutDrag(getApplicationContext(), 2));
FrameLayout.LayoutParams  param1 = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

The reason is because your second call overwrites your first, and you never listen for hut type of 1 to be dragged, because you passed which hut you are listening for in your constructor.

The solution to this is to change your assignment of the listener, like so:

```
findViewById(R.id.topHalf).setOnDragListener(new ColonyHutDrag(getApplicationContext()));
findViewById(R.id.bottomHalf).setOnDragListener(new ColonyHutDrag(getApplicationContext());
FrameLayout.LayoutParams  param1 = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

We're going to make an abstract class `ColonyHut`, and define `public int getType();`.

Get rid of your constructor for `ColonyHutListener` as well, we won't need that. Then you're going to make a class called `ColonyHutOne`, if you don't already have one. With that class, you're going to want to extend `ColonyHut`, and define `getType()` like so:

```
public int getType()
{
    return 1;
}
```

Then we'll define a function in your `ColonyHutDrag` class, called `setType()` like so:

```
public void setType(int type)
{
    buildingNum = type;
}
```

After that you're going to want to get the `ColonyHutOne` as a `ColonyHut`, like so `ColonyHut currentlySelectedHut = view.getHutFromView()` in your `onTouchListener`, and call `colonyHutDrag.setType(currentlySelectedHut.getType())` before `v.startDrag()` and it should work. Do the same for `ColonyHutTwo`, except obviously then you should make `getType()` return 2.

I'll leave defining `view.getHutFromView()`, and making `colonyHutDrag` visible in your `BuildingsClick` class. After all EVERYTHING can't be a free-be :-).

Comment: So I tried what you said but in the BuildingsClick class it wants me to change the identifier for the getType to static which in turn requires me change setType to static and then buildingNum to static. By doing this buildingNum is no longer subject to change like I need it to be.

Comment: `Static` variables can still be changed as long as they're not `final`, so technically it can still be changed, but I understand where you're coming from. Why does your IDE want getType to be `static`? Anyways your biggest problem with your code is your assigning a listener to `R.id.topHalf` and then you're overwriting it a few lines down with another assignment. You can't do that. It will not listen for both it will only listen for the last assigned (active) listener.

Comment: Looking into the issue, I believe the IDE is suggesting you make your method static because it's confused. How are you calling `getType()`, how did you declare it in your abstract class, and how did you declare it in both `ColonyHut` class files?

Comment: I understand that. I have changed it so that the onDragListeners are only used once in the beginning so all buildings use the same listener.

Comment: I added some code at the bottom of the question for you.